# Canvas drawImage by division background sprites

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite

i am trying to set some image objects inside canvas elements (working very well) with sprites (stop working well..):

> Heads up: The code is simplified!

*HTML*

```
<canvas id="canvasMap" width="600" height="600"></canvas> 
<div id="playerLeft"></div>
```

*JS*

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasMap');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.src = $($(document).find('#playerLeft').get(0)).css('background').replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');

img.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

*CSS*

```
#playerLeft {
    left: 0px;
    height:58px;
    display:block;
    width: 80px;
    background: url('/assets/sprites/angle.png') -0px -70px;
}
```

*RESULT (Developer Console)*

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/rgba(0,%200,%200,%200)%20url(http://example.com/assets/spr…png)%20repeat%20scroll%200px%20-70px%20/%20auto%20padding-box%20border-box"
```

*THE QUESTION*

How can i made it, that the declared Image Object receives the background sprite by css defined id? I would like to solve it without a third party lib.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's one way to fetch the dataURL of a div's background-image:**

```
// get the dataURL of your div's background
var bg = $('#sprite1').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace('"','').replace('"','');
```

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// get the dataURL of your div's background
var bg = $('#sprite1').css('background-image');
bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','').replace('"','').replace('"','');
// build an image from the dataURL
var img=new Image();
//img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
img.onload=function(){
  // draw the image onto the canvas
  ctx.drawImage(img,20,20);
}
img.src=bg;
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#sprite1{
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:75px;
  height:75px;
  background-image:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sun.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=sprite1>Sprite1</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how to use the whole background image from a division. But i need only a part. That's why we're using sprites.. I don't need the WHOLE image.. So, can you tell me, how to make this, too?

Comment: Sure, once you have the whole background image, you can use the clipping version of context.drawImage to clip your desired sprite from the whole image. If you haven't working with that version of drawImage before, here is a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage. Good luck with your project!

Comment: This is aweseome and exactly that what i am searched for!